# most efficient way to get current time/date/day in C

Tags: c, freebsd, systemtime, processing-efficiency

What is the most efficient way of getting current time/date/day/year in C language? As I have to execute this many times, I need a real efficient way. 
I am on freeBSD.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you profiled your code and found that accessing the date/time is the bottle neck?

Comment: Yes Daniel. 
I found that issue while trying to get current date by calling 'date' cmd from an awk script. That piece is called very frequently and is a little costly. 
Just try to call "date" cmd in a shell script 10000 times in a loop and you will realize. 

This is the reason I am trying to write that module in C instead of awk. 

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using GNU Awk, then you can use the [`strftime()`](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_13.html#SEC128) builtin awk function, rather than shelling out to an external command.

Comment: Thanks caf, I am using NAWK. I dont think strftime is available there. Would you be knowing of any other alternative in NAWK?

Comment: I don't believe there is - the easiest solution may simply be to install `gawk`.

Comment: Humm, thats not an option sadly. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard C provides only one way to get the time - `time()` - which can be converted to a time/date/year with `localtime()` or `gmtime()`.  So trivially, that must be the most efficient way.

Any other methods are operating-system specific, and you haven't told us what operating system you're using.

Comment: Thanks much. I am on freeBSD.

Comment: If you're worried about `gmtime` or `localtime` being slow, you could simply call them once and then adjust the results based on a delta value given in seconds obtained from `time`. This is portable as far as POSIX is concerned, but not plain C, as plain C does not specify the format of the `time_t` type except that it's an arithmetic type.

Answer (score 6):

```
/* ctime example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;

  time ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "The current local time is: %s", ctime (&rawtime) );

  return 0;
}
```

You can use [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/ctime/), if you need it as a string.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you mean by "many" :-)

I think you'll probably find that using the ISO standard `time()` and `localtime()` functions will be more than fast enough. For example, on my `"Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E6850 @ 3.00GHz"`, using unoptimised code, I can call `time()` ten million times in 1.045 seconds, and a `time()/localtime()` combination half a million times in 0.98 seconds. Whether that's fast enough for your needs, only you can decide, but I'm hard-pressed trying to come up with a use case that needs more grunt than that.

The `time()` function gives you the number of seconds since the epoch, while `localtime()` both converts it to local time (from UTC) and splits it into a more usable form, the `struct tm` structure.

```
#include <time.h>
time_t t = time (NULL);
struct tm* lt = localtime (&t);
// Use lt->tm_year, lt->tm_mday, and so forth.
```

Any attempt to cache the date/time and use other ways of finding out a delta to apply to it, such as with `clock()`, will almost invariably:

- be slower; and
- suffer from the fact you won't pick up external time changes.

Comment: Of course if many means 100s of times/second - then you could just cache the response and check if time() has changed every 100calls

Comment: @Martin, that's fine right up until the point where his process is switched out for a second because of massive system loads :-)

Comment: @Martin: the only problem with that is that unless you're *sure* it's going to be called many times a second, this could easily end up returning stale data.

Comment: time() only has a resolution of a second so it's unlikey that a process running 100Hz would care if 10% of the values were tagged with the previous second

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is

```
#include <time.h>
//...
time_t current_time = time (NULL);
struct tm* local_time = localtime (&current_time); 
printf ("the time is %s\n", asctime (local_time));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use gettimeofday() function to get time in seconds & microseconds which is (I think) very fast (as there is a similar function in Linux kernel do_gettimeofday()) and then you can convert it to your required format (might possible to use functions mentioned above for conversion.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just about the *only* way (that's standard, anyway) is to call `time` followed by `localtime` or `gmtime`.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the most straightforward response. The fact he's already working in C is of great benefit, the only hit here is the syscall for time?

Answer (score 0):

well, in general, directly accessing the OS's API to get the time is probably the most efficient,  but not so portable.....

the C time functions are ok.

But really depends on your platform

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a one second resolution is enough, the most efficient way on FreeBSD (or any POSIX system) is likely

- Install a one second interval timer with `setitimer (ITIMER_REAL, ...)`
- When it triggers the `SIGALRM`, update a static variable holding the currrent time
- Use the value in the static variable whenever you need the time

Even if signals get lost due to system overload this will correct itself the next time the process is scheduled.